# Node.js console.log performance

Tags: performance, node.js, console, logging

If your Node.js code is littered with console.log statements are you inviting performance issues? Is it worth debug/production toggling this on/off? I realized logging is important to prod in general - but I'm generally curious if the console output has a performance hit?

In Chrome it definitely seems to degrade performance if the console is open.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Edit:**

> console.log is synchronous and it is blocking the event loop

---

I think this is low hanging fruit, and will almost not give you any speed bump at all when you disable logging(if not used rigorously  in critical parts). Probably the console.log is implemented in pure C. Also there are some modules available which can turn off logging in production, just as you can do with [socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/logger.js):

- https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node
- https://github.com/visionmedia/log.js

Comment: @Raynos than even better, but still using a library to have log levels can come in handy.

Comment: @Raynos wrong. It greatly effects performance.  I just did a test with console.log with 60,000 keys in my `GAMES` object. Then, simply did a `for in` to check if a property exists while console logging the GAMES object before checking.  And there was a noticeable delay. (3-5 seconds)  I removed the console log and re-checked the property again and it was instant. This is a HUGE issue because that delay makes your system very vulnerable if you're using a rate limiter inside node. (Limiter will not run properly (or any code) until the io is finished, and very dangerous).

Comment: Please note that `console.log` is **synchronous** and it is blocking the event loop.

Comment: Hmmm prod is probably the environment which most badly needs logs...

Answer (score 26):

console.log calls in nodejs are synchronous(!) and block the event loop. I just experienced that when I logged the results from executing (asynchronous) sql queries with pg. Logging only 20 items and their (few) properties decreased the performance from 3ms to 300ms on my local machine.

Answer (score 12):

`console.log` slows down chrome because it is actually interfacing with the DOM on every call.  The entire `inspect element` system is actually just tons of DOM elements.  When you call `console.log` in the browser it it having to append a new element to the `console` on every call.

You can see how `console.log` is really just HTML by right clicking on an element in `console` and clicking `inspect element`.  This will in fact open a new `console` inspecting an already existing `console`. :D

If you are really that worried about performance you could always remove the `console.log` feature completely(not really advised because it could get confusing).  You basically can `noop` the function in the browser or server side.  No more `console.log` no more speed impact :D

```
console.log=function(){};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I voted this up but selected @Alfred as the answer because it answered specifically for node. But that info on chrome and why it's different was useful.

Comment: (at least on slow machines at work) The chrome issue is very noticeable once you log >1000 items to the log.  It only slows down when you have the dev tools open though, so shouldn't be a problem in production for most users.

Comment: @UpTheCreek it still is synchronous

Comment: Are there any libraries that can be used by client side libraries and provide better performance compared to console log?

Comment: @TGW you could simply append the value to a variable that is displayed periodically using setTimeout.

Answer (score -9):

As said above, the `console.log` is asynchronous and non-blocking, so it would not slow your application too much except one tick for the function invocation.

But it is a good habit to use some module to turn some logs of certain level off when deploy it in production instead of using console.log directly. There have been several good ones as @Alfred listed.

The Nodejs official blog posted an article suggesting use JSON format for logging, check it out at [Service logging in JSON with Bunyan](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/03/28/service-logging-in-json-with-bunyan/), and [Bunyan for nodejs](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) is really worth trying.

Comment: Please note that `console.log` is **synchronous** and it is blocking the event loop