# Console.log in a production app using node.js, express and PM2

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I'm using console.log for debugging some information in my web app using node.js, expressjs and PM2. All is working fine :)

I want to know if my web app can have performance problems in production if I use console.log this:

```
var myVariable = "Enter in this section of code";
console.log(myVariable);
```

I have read about console.log is synchronous and can affect to my performance... if this is real in this moment (I'm using **Express 4**), how can I remove these console.log in different environments like production?

I'm using PM2 (**pm2 logs** command) to watch the logs and **pm2 flush** to clean the logs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) for logging , you could configure transport depending on your env , for example you could use Console and File tranports in development and just File in production. PD: pm2 takes data from std log(console)

Comment: Thanks for the information @cshion Can you please confirm my question? Could I have performance problems with console.log like I have configured? Thank again

Comment: since console.log is sync , could affect performance ( for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853566/node-js-console-log-performance ) , winston internally manages async logging.

Comment: Thanks, I will check winstom

Comment: its tricky , thats why i said that pm2 takes data from std io. there are some alternative loggers  like log4js , bunyan ,etc . you can check many options and use what do you think is better for your case.