# More efficient way to parse JSON and map to an array in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with an API to parse stock market data in NodeJS.

The program works fine up to around 30K transactions per second, which is fine for the slower parts of the day.  During market open though, it can exceed 100K transactions per second and the heap explodes to 30GB+, lagging and eventually crashing, despite being on an extremely fast machine.

I'm relatively new to NodeJS, but the bottleneck appears to be the below section of code, I obtained from a sample client that is in an extension of the EventEmitter class.

```
   onMessage( data ){
        data = JSON.parse( data )
        data.map(( msg ) => {
            if( msg.ev === 'status' ){
                console.log('Status Update:', msg.message)
            }
            this.emit(msg.ev, msg)
        })
```

Is there a more efficient way to code this that could give a 2x+ speed improvement? The individual bits of JSON are quite small such as the following:

```
{
 "ev": "T",
 "sym": "MSFT",
 "x": 4,
 "i": "12345",
 "z": 3,
 "p": 114.125,
 "s": 100,
 "c": [
  0,
  12
 ],
 "t": 1536036818784
}
```

Comment: Well, to start with, it would be  lot more efficient to send one message with all the data rather than a separate message for each iteration of `data.map()` and let the client iterate through them itself.  That would drastically reduce the number of separate messages you send.  If this array has lots of items in it, this could easily be 10x or more efficient for your server (depending upon the size of the array).

Comment: That makes sense, but I am processing and responding to the data in real time from an API that feeds them to me one at a time in real time. So that makes it difficult to do them in bulk.  Is a pretty extreme variation in how fast the data comes in from as little as one every few seconds around 5am to as many as one million in a second at the market closing bell.

Comment: Uhhh, `data.map()` is processing whatever you have one at a time instead of in bulk.  I'm suggesting you get rid of that entire loop.  Also, if you are regularly getting these ms apart, then you can accumulate them for one client for 100ms or 1000ms or whatever time delay is appropriate for your app and send all that have accumulated at once.  The entire point here is to stop sending zillions of tiny messages.  That's enormously inefficient for the server.

Comment: `map()` constructs an array of the results of all the callback functions. Use `forEach()` if you don't need this array. This will save some memory.

Comment: You might use the new iterator approach... `for (const msg of data) { ... }`  In any case, I'd recommend finding a way to partition your data processing across multiple hosts.

Comment: It's not clear how often it's firing, but [console.log is quite slow in node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24980354/4166522), so taking that out may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my comments, I suggested you take the `data.map()` loop out and send all that at once and then let the client iterate through the individual pieces:

```
   onMessage( data ){
        data = JSON.parse( data )
        this.emit("multiMsg", data);
   }
```

Then, the client would have this:

```
   socket.on("multiMsg", (data) => {
        for (const item of data) {
            // process each item here
            console.log(item);
        }
   });
```

If you're still getting lots of `onMessage()` calls in rapid fire, you can accumulate them for a short period of time (the time to choose depends upon the acceptable time delay for your app). That also allows you to drastically reduce the number of separate messages you send to the client during high traffic times which can be many, many times more efficient for the server.   So, if you would have received 100 calls to `onMessage()` within 50ms, then this modification will send one accumulated message to the client, instead of 100 separate messages to the client.

Here's an idea how that could work:

```
   const msgQueueTime = 500;    // pick an appropriate time delay here
   let msgQueue = [];
   let msgQueueTimer = null;

   onMessage( data ){
        data = JSON.parse( data )
        if (!msgQueueTimer) {
            msgQueueTimer = setTimeout(() => {
                // send data we have accumulated
                this.emit("multiMsg", msgQueue);
                msgQueue = [];
                msgQueueTimer = null;
            }, msgQueueTime);
        }
        // add data onto our queue array
        msgQueue.push(...data);
   }
```

Comment: Erm... how is putting a delay in going to speed up the processing?  I'm missing something here.

Comment: @RichN - It allows you to accumulate incoming messages for a short period of time and send 1 message to the client containing all the data rather than sending 1000 separate messages to the client.  That is way, way more efficient for the server.  The OP states they are often sending zillions of these messages and the server is having trouble doing that.  This is a means of making that way, way more efficient so the server can keep up.  This is similar to how it's more efficient for you to go the supermarket once and get 10 items, than to go 10 times to get 1 item each time.

Comment: Oh I see.  But since node is singlethreaded aren't we probably just moving the iteration to a different bit of the same program at a later point in time?  My impression is this code is in the client and we aren't sending these messages on to a different process.  I may be wrong.

Comment: @RichN - Well, there's a lot more overhead involved in sending 1000 messages than sending 1 message with all 1000 bits of data.  So, singlethreaded or not, it's just a lot more efficient to send fewer messages containing multiple pieces of data rather than lots of separate messages.  This is true for any data you send across the network or write to a file, etc... and has nothing to do with threading.

Comment: @RichN - FYI, he's talking about 100K transactions per second and mentions nodejs.  That's significant overhead if you send every one of those separately to some client.

Comment: Impressed. I was able to integrate your code (without modification) and use a for loop to process the results given by the emitter. The application is functional, but very little data this time of night. Let me try this when markets reopen on Friday morning and report back about the performance difference.  Probably do end up hitting some other bottleneck, but after this I can start filtering data out.

Comment: @RyanP - Is this `.emit()` just local?  Or is it sending over a network?  If it's only local, this likely won't make much of a difference.  When I wrote this, I thought this was sending to a remote client over a socket (like with socket.io).

Comment: “Accumulate data for a time” might be better as “accumulate for a count or a time, whichever is reached first”.

Comment: It's just local...thought about removing the emit altogether, but not really sure which parts of javascript consume resources.  This method reduces the number of calls to data.map massively....so guess see.  Later on in the process a small subset of this data is written to a Redis database, and other NodeJS applications make use of that.

Comment: @RyanP - OK, then I'm not sure how much this will help if it's all local.   I could see how a peak load of 100K transactions per second may be sending your CPU to 100% and not leaving time for garbage collection.  It would be very important to see the entire process for one of those transactions and minimize the number of separate Javascript objects created (that then need to be garbage collected).

Comment: `EventEmitter.emit()` is fairly efficient by itself (just iterating an array of listeners and making a function call for each listener).

Comment: @danh - Yes, that would be an option too.  It's a little hard to know how to best implement this when we can't see the whole problem or run any metrics on it.

Comment: Is running right now on a 12 core Mac Pro 192GB Ram...it mostly runs in the 10-60% of one CPU core range, but spikes very close to 200% at the peak of the open. (Not exactly sure how it manages to keep two cores busy) The application can handle just ignoring the first moments of the open, but right now the load is too high for the first 15-30 mins, and in usual market conditions could be more. Splitting the load into different apps/machines is somewhat possible, but the data access costs are high and are per connection. The Redis database never gets above 15% CPU.

Comment: Right now the heap size is about 50MB, but it managed to hit 32GB between 9:31 and 9:34 this morning and crash out.

Comment: @RyanP - A detailed review of everywhere you're causing objects to get allocated and simplifying the process from start to finish can make a massive difference.  That requires thorough examine of end-to-end code for processing each item to reduce the total number of objects the garbage collector has to deal with and thus reduce the peak memory usage.

Comment: Yes not sure how to provide that, but your thought about the CPU being too busy to garbage collect makes sense.  I probably could do some work to eliminate anything non essential in this single program.  If the program does not exceed the max heap size I have set, the memory utilization will quickly wind back down...from tens of GB's to a couple hundred megabytes as market activity slows down.  My knowledge of javascript garbage collection is limited.

Comment: The batch method you subscribed did it. Thank you!  I also needed to take out everything non essential happening after processing each JSON object, and put those items in batches of their own to happen periodically.  I've been able process as many as 1 million transactions in a second after these changes.  Which seems needed as we had a rate of over 400K transactions per second this morning.